# How can I set the inside text of an <a> element vertically in the middle?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have an `<a>` tag containing a background image and text. The problem is that the text sticks to the top of the image.

```
<a class="BigBlueButton" href="/where-is-my-order.aspx">
    Where Is My Order?
</a>
```

And my CSS is as follows:

```
.BigBlueButton
{
    width: 233px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    height: 122px;
    background: url(../img/GreenBotton.png) no-repeat;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    display: inline-block;
    color: White;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I have used *line-height*, but for tags with little bit larger texts the whole text does not display.

What is it with given the CSS and HTML content:

[image: Normal one]

And what I get with *line-height*:

[image: With line-height]

Comment: Could you provide jsFiddle with your problem, please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KZL2p/ there you go

Comment: FYI your link has the class `BigBlueButton` but the CSS you posted is for `BiGreenButton`

Comment: Well, could you give an example where `line-height` doesn't meet your requirements?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div

Comment: @amir I thought so, that's why I gave a +1 to Adrift's answer. It's the only way.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell, OK lets use Line-height, I am wondering if I can wrap the text some how then?

Comment: @amir I gave my +1 to the `display: table-cell` solution, not to the `line-height`.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell, aha, sorry!
I have 12 of these boxes in my page, using Display:Table-Cell blow everything up. 
There is no alternatives?

Comment: @amir There is an answer for every possible way. With one of those you'll have to live, sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's The Best Way of Centering a Div Vertically with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css)

Comment: A design comment - if you can, try and make those boxes a bit more subtle. Strong gradients like the ones you have are distracting and they make text harder to read.

Comment: I added padding-top, That's better option for me, however its not the best!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align text vertically center in div with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, finally I found the following workaround:

```
<a href="www.mydoamin.com" class="div_a">
    <span class="wrapper">
      <span class="div_txt">Contentdas asd ad adasd asd asdad </span>
    </span>
</a>
<a href="www.mydoamin.com" class="div_a">
    <span class="wrapper">
        <span class="div_txt">Content</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

And the following CSS

```
a.div_a {
    display: inline-table;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    background-image: url(http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png);
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WcCnW/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Just change `display: inline-block;` to `display: table-cell;`

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KZL2p/1/)

Comment: @LinusCaldwell - there's [nearly 95% browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell), and you can add an acceptable fallback for old IE with `padding` or `line-height` if needed.

Comment: Dispay:Table-cell blow up all my page, I have 12 of these images in my page and they should be in line

Comment: Please be more specific. What does "blow up" mean?

Comment: @LinusCaldwell please see Update3!

Comment: Ok, and how should it look like? With the `width` set, I would say it looks like it should.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell: Update4 shows how it looks like and its almost ok except the text vertical alignment!

Comment: Well, in that case I'm afraid you'll have to use a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation you'll have to use a wrapper like a `<span/>`. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DPDpg/):

```
<a href="#"><span>Text</span></a>
```

With this CSS content:

```
a
{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

span
{
    width: 233px;
    height: 122px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a div with padding.
I don’t know if it's best practice though.
Obviously, put the background in the div of the right size and use correct padding.

```
<a href="test.php">
    <div style="padding:10px;width:150px;border:1px #000 solid;text-align:center;">
        Hello!
    </div>
</a>
```